# React Native: Rerender FlatList when toggle button is pressed on a row item

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how I'm supposed to accomplish this despite reading the documentation and pages of similar questions.

I have a list of items where each item can be individually displayed either using its name in text for compact viewing, or an image for full viewing. I have a native base icon setup to toggle the display choice. I know it works because it will update my view if I click it and navigate away and back again.

Array of objects with a prop for view toggle, and a prop for the data

```
data[{imgView: false, data:data}, {...}]
```

The data is static with the only change being filters for what is shown.
I've tried using the extraData prop but it I can't get it to work properly. If I use it with a state property it errors because where I need to perform the setState is in the render function which is obviously not going to work. I tried making a global variable to reference but it doesn't do anything. I don't know how to reference the prop in my row item to use that.

I tried using componentWillReceiveProps but I don't know how I can reference the props in my data objects and it didn't seem to work with just a setState call without a check in place for testing.

What I'm trying to do is:
press button in row item -> toggles view property for that row item only
toggled row item property -> triggers rerender of the list

Edit: Adding some code pieces

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: result,
    update: false
  };
};

_renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <Image source={item.imgView ? 
      images[item.data.imgFull] : 
      images[item.data.name]} 
      style={{flex:1}}
    />
    <Icon name="arrow-dropdown" 
      style={{color:'black'}}
      onPress ={() => {item.imgView = !item.imgView}}
    />
  );
);

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      extraData={this.state.update}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} //to remove warning for now
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
  );
};
```

I don't know if I'm going about this properly, but when the onPress in the icon component of the _renderItem function is called I'd like to toggle the state.update so the extraData forces a rerender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is static, I would not store it in state. I would move the "item" out to its own component and use that component's state to indicate whether it is open or not.

```
export default class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  toggleView = () => {
    const { open } = this.state;
    this.setState(() => ({ open: !open });
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <Image source={open ? 
        images[item.data.imgFull] : 
        images[item.data.name]} 
        style={{flex:1}}
      />
      <Icon name="arrow-dropdown" 
        style={{color:'black'}}
        onPress ={this.toggleView}
      />
    );
  }
}

 // In your current List component
_renderItem = ({item}) => <ListItem item={item} />;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Do I add ListItem.state as the extraData to trigger the rerender of the list since the data source doesn't change?

Comment: Only the individual ListItem component that has been toggled should rerender, not the entire list. You shouldn't need to pass anything from ListItem to extraData.

Comment: Thanks, just got it working. I'm new to mobile and react, also wanted to thank you for a clear example that shows how props work. I've been struggling to understand exactly how they're set and used, this cleared it up a lot for me.

Comment: Any time, glad I could help!